# Can Internet Explorer 7 run on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

I need to run IE7 on my Windows 7 machine due to applications that currently do not support IE8. Is this possible?

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 4):

IE8 has an IE7 compatibility mode. That might work for you

Answer (score 3):

There are also "IE App Compat" virtual machines for VirtualPC. There are several different virtual machines for different Windows versions with different versions of IE installed. For example, you can download an IE8 XP VM or an IE7 Vista VM.

You can get them [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en).

Comment: Or install XP Mode, which comes with IE6 and upgrade it to IE7 (and you should be able to use the extra integration features of XP MOde so the VM is less obvious).

Comment: He might not have 7 Professional, which includes XP mode.

Answer (score 1):

IE7 is officially not supported on Windows 7. Does the application work in compatibility mode? Can you use Windows XP Mode and install IE7 in that?